# Django: Validate CSV

Tags: python, django, csv

i have this model,

```
class user2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

and a csv file that contains the information like this:

```
number,0001,0002,0003, ...
```

So, i need to check if the number that i take from the csv exists, if not, i create a user with the django user model, then create the user2 user, right now im trying this, to check if the number exists in the db

```
def import_csv(path):
    path = "/home/ad/ds/Web.csv"
    with open(path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
           try:
               if not user2.objects.filter(number=int(row[0])).exists():
                   print "no"
           except:
               print "asd "
```

but when i do this i get this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'number'
```

how i can do this? thanks

Comment: yes, number is an int  @summea

Comment: ``.exists()`` don;t forget the brackets

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occuring because you are trying to cast the first csv value which is a string in your csv file to an `int` here:

```
if not user2.objects.filter(number=int(row[0])).exists():
```

You could change your code to this to skip the first csv value being a string and go from the second value `0001`

```
try:
    if not user2.objects.filter(number=int(row[1])).exists():
        #do stuff
except ValueError:
    # csv value was not an int
```

Comment: always enters in the except, why is this happening? the db is empty, so every time i check it should enter to the if

Comment: The first value in your csv file looks to be a string, when you cast a string to an int using `int()` it will throw a `ValueError`. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: i cant do that, because the row[1] is another thing in the CSV, my csv is a giant file, im user "numer" as a example